# ggplot proportion bar fill with categorical variable got Error Message

Tags: r

I am trying to use fill by barplot (Proportion) with one categorical variable, but got the error `message:Error in rep(value[[k]], length.out = n) : attempt to replicate an object of type 'closure'`.

The dataset I am using is diamond under `ggplot2`, here is my code:

```
bar_1 <- ggplot(data = diamonds) + geom_bar(
mapping = aes(x = cut, y=stat(prop), group=1), fill=cut), 
show.legend = FALSE)
```

Can anyone let me know the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Since `cut` is a variable in your data frame, it needs to be mapped to its aesthetic, in this case `fill`, inside of the `aes()`

```
bar_1 <- ggplot(data = diamonds) + geom_bar(
mapping = aes(x = cut, y=stat(prop), group=1, fill=cut), 
show.legend = FALSE)
```

As a result of placing `fill=cut` outside of `aes`, `cut` was interpreted as the function `base::cut()`, an object of type closure, which threw an error when `ggplot` attempted to assign it to the `fill` aesthetic of `geom_bar`

Comment: In this case, there will not be any color applied to the bar. Do you know  how I can fix it?

Comment: Yes, what you need is actually `y = stat(count)`, or `y = ..count..`, and `group` can then be omitted.  For example: `bar_1 <- ggplot(data = diamonds) + geom_bar(
mapping = aes(x = cut, y=stat(count), fill=cut), 
show.legend = FALSE)`